# Can I be notified of an activity result that is declared as singleTask?

Tags: android

My activity is interacting with other activities by sending intent to them. The requirements I have is :
- to be notified when the activity launched is finished
- know the result code.

On most of the use cases this is working with a startActivityForResult as my activity is set to singleTask.

But when I'm interacting with activities that are also declared as singleTask this method doesn't work. This is because the new activity is creating its own task and the OnActivityResult of my activity is immediately called once the new activity is launched.

Unfortunately I can't change the properties for those activities as these are 3rd party ones.

Is there a way for my activity to be notified in case I call a singleTask activity ?